# Spring Security Custom Login And Custom Authentication Provider

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

i'm creating a project with spring security for login, this is part of my project, i want to use custom login page and custom authentication provider i've searched for tutorials but i'm ended in the custom login page showed up but, the user cannot login, (access denied) received instead in the stack trace, here is my code, i prefer full java configuration.

this is my security config class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan("id.config.configPack")
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{


 @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider authProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(
      AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
    }

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         http.csrf().disable();
         http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/menu")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()                                    
                .permitAll();

}

}
```

this is for initializing to the project

```
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends 
AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

public SecurityWebApplicationInitializer() {
    super(SecurityConfig.class);
}
}
```

this is my custom auth provider

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) 
  throws AuthenticationException {

    String user = authentication.getName();
    String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
    List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<>();
    grantedAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
    if (user.equalsIgnoreCase("test") && password.equals("test")) {        
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                (user, password, grantedAuths);
    } else {
        throw new BadCredentialsException("Authentication failed");
    }

}

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return authentication.equals(
      UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
}
}
```

this is my login page, i didn't specify the action because from what i know spring security take control of that, CMIW.

```
<form id="loginForm" class="login-form">
    <input name="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" />
    <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    <br />
    <br />
    <span id="err" class="errMsg"></span>
</form>
```

i'm also defined a controller class for login page and for the sucess login page.

my expected result is i can logged in and redirected to the default login sucess handler in my security config, is there any code that missing or required? 
Thanks

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Comment: mine I can't get the username and password from the Custom Authentication Provider

Comment: you need to specify the action to goto `/login` and the method has to be `post`.

Answer (score 0):

no the action must be login and the method must be post or you can ovveride action like that
.formLogin().loginPage("/login").loginProcessingUrl("/auth")

you need to add thing to java class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class BasicAuthConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()

            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/loginPage")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/auth")
            .successHandler(successHandler())
            .failureHandler(failureHandler())
            .permitAll()

            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutSuccessHandler(new HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler(HttpStatus.OK))
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .permitAll();
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    return new CustomAuthenticationProvider();
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
}

private AuthenticationEntryPoint getRestAuthenticationEntryPoint() {
    return new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/app/dist/*");
}

private AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler() {
    return new AuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                                            HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Authentication authentication)
                throws IOException, ServletException {
            httpServletResponse.setStatus(200);
            Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = authentication.getAuthorities();
            if(authorities.toString().contains("ROLE_ADMIN")){
                httpServletResponse.setHeader("role", "ROLE_ADMIN");
            } else if(authorities.toString().contains("ROLE_NOPRICED")){
                httpServletResponse.setHeader("role", "ROLE_NOPRICED");
            }
        }
    };
}

private AuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler() {
    return new AuthenticationFailureHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                                            HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, AuthenticationException e)
                throws IOException, ServletException {
            httpServletResponse.setStatus(401);
        }
    };
}
```

}

Comment: how to achieve this in SecurityFilterChain latest spring security?